# Папка values-sw320dp. Не используется вместе с ldpi

Tags: android, java

Как я понимаю sw<n>dp вычисляется так: берется наименьшая сторона и делится на dpi экрана. Пробовал запускать на эмуляторе ldpi плотностью , 240*320 пикс. Если я прав то smallestWidth для этого эмулятора = 320dp. Но почему то значения берутся из папки values, а не values-sw320dp.  [В хелпе](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)  сказано :

```
Some values you might use here for common screen sizes:
320, for devices with screen configurations such as:
-240x320 ldpi (QVGA handset)
-320x480 mdpi (handset)
-480x800 hdpi (high density handset)
```

и я непонимаю почему 240*320 пикс , ldpi устройство не берет нужные значения из нужной папки. Андроид 4,0.
Кстати говоря, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi работает нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена путем замены эмулятора 4,0,3 на версию 4,4. видимо баг был какойто.

Answer (score -2):

вы не учитываете тот факт что "размер экрана" != "размер программы" 
можете поставить [Screen Size / DPI and Dev Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sturnus.screeninfo) или аналоги и убедиться в этом.

надо из 240*320 вычесть размер status bar и navigation bar, а если Multi Window?

Comment: 1)на моем нексус 7 наименьшая сторона равна 552dp (благодаря системным кнопкам), однако значения считываются из папки values-sw600dp. 
2) на эмуляторе 240х320 ldpi Значения полученные DisplayMetrics показывают что наименьшая сторона в пикселях равна 240, density=0.75.
И она в упор не хочет брать из папки values-sw320dp. Сделав тоже самое на другом эмуляторе - 480х800 hdpi прога успешно взяла значения из папки values-sw320dp. 
3) Опытным путем мне удалось сделать так чтобы эмулятор 240х320 ldpi брал значения хоть из какойто папки. ей оказалась values-sw240dp. НО это же бред.